# Unable to create managed bean, Property for managed bean aircraftMB does not exist

Tags: java, spring, jsf, primefaces

I found a lot of solutions about this matter, but no one solved my issue.
Here's my managed bean:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedProperty;
import javax.faces.bean.RequestScoped;
import com.bombardier.domain.Aircraft;
import com.bombardier.domain.WorkPackage;
import com.bombardier.services.DBDataManipulatorService;

@ManagedBean(name = "aircraftMB")
@RequestScoped
public class AircraftManagedBean implements Serializable{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

//Spring User Service is injected...
@ManagedProperty(value="#{DBDataManipulatorServiceImpl}")
DBDataManipulatorService dbDataManipulatorService;

List<Aircraft> aircrafts;

private int aircraftId;
private String type;
private String model;
private Map<String, WorkPackage> workPackagesMap;


public List<Aircraft> getAircrafts() {

    aircrafts = new ArrayList<Aircraft>();
    aircrafts = dbDataManipulatorService.findAllAircrafts();

    return aircrafts;
}

public DBDataManipulatorService getDBDataManipulatorServiceImpl() {

    return dbDataManipulatorService;
}


public void setDBDataManipulatorServiceImpl(DBDataManipulatorService dbDataManipulatorService) {

    this.dbDataManipulatorService = dbDataManipulatorService;

}


public void setAircrafts(List<Aircraft> aircrafts) {
    this.aircrafts = aircrafts;
}

public int getAircraftId() {
    return aircraftId;
}

public void setAircraftId(int aircraftId) {
    this.aircraftId = aircraftId;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public String getModel() {
    return model;
}

public void setModel(String model) {
    this.model = model;
}


public Map<String, WorkPackage> getWorkPackagesMap() {
    return workPackagesMap;
}


public void setWorkPackagesMap(Map<String, WorkPackage> workPackagesMap) {
    this.workPackagesMap = workPackagesMap;
}
}
```

and my service is as follow:

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class DBDataManipulatorServiceImpl implements DBDataManipulatorService {

@Autowired
private AircraftRepository aircraftRepository;

@Autowired
private WorkPackageRepository workPackageRepository;

@Autowired
private MyJobRepository myJobRepository;

@Override
public Aircraft getAircraftById(String id) {

    return new Aircraft();
}

@Override
@Transactional
public Map<Integer, Aircraft> saveToDataBase(Map<Integer, Aircraft> aircraftsMap) {

    Map<Integer, Aircraft> newaircraftsMap = new HashMap<Integer, Aircraft>();
    Aircraft newAircraft = null;
    for (Aircraft aircraft : aircraftsMap.values()) {
        newAircraft = aircraftRepository.save(aircraft);
        newaircraftsMap.put(newAircraft.getAircraftId(), newAircraft);
    }

    return newaircraftsMap;
}

@Override
@Transactional
public MyJob findJobByJobId(String jobId) {

    MyJob job = myJobRepository.findOne(jobId);
    if (job == null) {

    }

    return job;
}

@Override
@Transactional
public WorkPackage findWorkPackageByAircraftIdAndWorkPackageId(
        int aircraftId, String workPackageId) {

    WorkPackage workPackage = workPackageRepository
            .findWorkPackageByWorkPackageIdAndAircraftId(aircraftId,
                    workPackageId);

    return workPackage;
}

@Override
@Transactional
public Aircraft findAircraftByaircraftId(int aircraftId) {

    return aircraftRepository.findOne(aircraftId);
}

@Override
@Transactional
public List<Aircraft> findAllAircrafts() {

    List<Aircraft> aircrafts;

    aircrafts = aircraftRepository.findAll();

    return aircrafts;

}
}
```

and I get the following error:

```
Unable to create managed bean aircraftMB. The following problems were found: - Property dbDataManipulatorService for managed bean aircraftMB does not exist. Check that appropriate getter and/or setter methods exist.
```

can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you intend to inject an EJB not an other managed-bean, If so, inject it like the following:

```
@EJB
private DBDataManipulatorService dbDataManipulatorService;
```

Comment: The old error message gone but I got: 'java.lang.NullPointerException: null' br/
at com.web.AircraftManagedBean.getAircrafts(AircraftManagedBean.java:38). can you tell me what's the problem?

Comment: This probably means that `dbDataManipulatorService` is not injected properly into the managed-bean. Did you try to run it with another method ?

Comment: No, any suggestion about that?

Answer (score 1):

According to the exception, `dbDataManipulatorService` can not be found by EL. That is because you have not provided the proper getter and setter for that property.

Try changing the name of these methods

```
public DBDataManipulatorService getDBDataManipulatorServiceImpl() {    
    return dbDataManipulatorService;
}


public void setDBDataManipulatorServiceImpl(DBDataManipulatorService dbDataManipulatorService) {    
    this.dbDataManipulatorService = dbDataManipulatorService;    
}
```

for these

```
public DBDataManipulatorService getDbDataManipulatorService() {    
    return dbDataManipulatorService;
}


public void setDbDataManipulatorService(DBDataManipulatorService dbDataManipulatorService) {    
    this.dbDataManipulatorService = dbDataManipulatorService;    
}
```

at least this specific exception will desappear

```
Unable to create managed bean aircraftMB. The following problems were found: - Property dbDataManipulatorService for managed bean aircraftMB does not exist. Check that appropriate getter and/or setter methods exist.
```

If after that you are still facing problems with the injection thing, this post could be useful [Spring DAO is not injected in JSF managed bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14766345/spring-dao-is-not-injected-in-jsf-managed-bean)

Comment: I like that you explain the reason for the described issue :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have the following: 
In faces-config.xml:

```
    <application>
         <el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
         ...
    </application>
```

Make sure you have these listeners in web.xml:

```
    <listener>
      <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <listener>
      <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
    </listener>
```

In your AircraftManagedBean:

```
    @Component
    public class AircraftManagedBean implements Serializable{

    @Autowired
    DBDataManipulatorService dbDataManipulatorService;
    ....
    }
```

Comment: I returned back to the old error message:   Unable to create managed bean aircraftMB. The following problems were found: - Property dbDataManipulatorService for managed bean aircraftMB does not exist. Check that appropriate getter and/or setter methods exist.

Comment: Did you check with my edited response of Component annotation for AircraftManagedBean and Autowired for DBDataManipulatorService? dbDataManipulatorService should be in the spring config file.

Comment: yeh, every thing was done, but steel have the problem

Comment: Can you post your spring config file?

Answer (score 0):

the problem is solved. in the userInterfaceBean added:

```
public UserInterfaceBean(){
    //Because the Autowire is not working
    WebApplicationContext ctx =  FacesContextUtils.getWebApplicationContext(FacesContext.getCurrentInstance());
    dbDataManipulatorService = ctx.getBean(DBDataManipulatorService.class);
}

@PostConstruct
public void Init() {

    aircrafts = new ArrayList<Aircraft>();
    aircrafts = dbDataManipulatorService.findAllAircrafts();

}
```

now I have the details I wanted in my view.