# Auto Repository with Spring Data

Tags: spring, jsf, spring-boot

I have a little problem in integrating spring with JSF.

I understood that either Spring and JSF have distinct containers. So I can't mix their annotations because registered beans will not be visible to each other.

However, I've read an article : [Spring DAO is not injected in JSF managed bean](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14766345/spring-dao-is-not-injected-in-jsf-managed-bean) where guy says that It's possible to annotate everything with spring annotations make visible these components to JSF.

I'm really confused with xml configuration because sometimes I read that I don't need it but in most cases I see people usually do this.

My question is what need to be configured if I have this source code and I want to make visible spring beans to JSF :

```
package pl.catarina.controller;


import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Scope;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import pl.catarina.domain.Patient;
import pl.catarina.repository.PatientRepository;
import javax.annotation.PostConstruct;
@Component
@Scope("request")
public class RegisterController {

    @Autowired
    private PatientRepository patientRepository;

    private Patient patient;


    @PostConstruct
    public void init(){
        patient = new Patient();
        patient.setName("jan");
        patient.setSurname("Way");
        patient.setPhoneNumber("21421131");
        patient.setEmail("asdpad@gmail.com");
        patient.setPassword("pdsad223Sdsd");
    }


    public void save(){
        patientRepository.save(patient);
    }


}
```

**REPOSITORY**

```
package pl.catarina.repository;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;
import pl.catarina.domain.Patient;

@Repository
public interface PatientRepository extends UserBaseRepository<Patient> {
        Patient findByEmail(String email);
}
```

**web.xml**

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xmlns = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:web = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         xsi:schemaLocation = "http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
         id = "WebApp_ID" version="2.5">

    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>pages/home.xhtml</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <!--
       FacesServlet is main servlet responsible to handle all request.
       It acts as central controller.
       This servlet initializes the JSF components before the JSP is displayed.
    -->

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.faces</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
        <param-value>client</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.PROJECT_STAGE</param-name>
        <param-value>Production</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.ocpsoft.pretty.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
        <param-value>true</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>primefaces.THEME</param-name>
        <param-value>bootstrap</param-value>
    </context-param>

</web-app>
```

Comment: This might help: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.0.M3/reference/html/ch04s04.html

Comment: Everything IS in the link you referred to. And keep in mind that recent Spring versions 'know' (parse) the CDI annotations. XML is not needed to make beans spring mananged beans that can be used in JSF. For other specific spring services you still might need xml config.